# Docker ports from old image in new container. How to remove?

Tags: docker, networking, tcp, port, docker-container

I have an initial `container1` which I run with this command:

```
docker run -p 801:8001 -ti --name container1 image:v1
```

After a while, I decided to commit this container with command:

```
docker commit container1 image:v2
```

I then decide to spin up another container running parallel beside this first container.

```
docker run -p 802:8002 -ti --name container2 image:v2
```

Now everything works fine but when I type:

```
docker ps -a
```

I note that under PORTS for `container1`:

```
0.0.0.0:801->8001/tcp
```

But under `container2`:

```
801/tcp, 0.0.0.0:802->8002/tcp
```

Two questions:

a) Currently it does not affect anything on my end since I am not outputting anything to port 801 under `container2` (I am running a Django server which I output it to 802 in `container2`), but I am assuming this is not ideal to have the open conflicting port even if it is not in use?

b) How do I remove `801/tcp` from `container2`? I assume it has inherited this behaviour from `container1` since I committed the image from it.

Thanks!

EDIT:
I did not write any Dockerfile myself but when I search in the root of my container this is what I get, do I show all?  I am guessing the last file is the one in question?

```
root@be539e23d836:/# find . -name Dockerfile
./usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/ext-runtime/nodejs/data/Dockerfile 
./usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/ext-runtime/go/data/Dockerfile 
./usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/docker/docker/Dockerfile
```

Comment: Provide your Dockerfile

Comment: I did not write any Dockerfile myself.  When I search in the base of my docker container I get three files.  I edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: What is the port exposed by your image? Having `801/tcp` under the ports section of your container description means that your container exposes port 801. If this is the case then maybe you have your port mappings the wrong way around. Please check that you use the form `docker run -p host_port:container_port`. If your image exposes `801` then `801` should be the second number after `-p`.